# Problem with connection accumulation in PHP and MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu

I'm using PHP 7.1 along with MongoDB 3.6.
Driver version is 1.74.

I'm encountering an issue where my connection count keeps on going up. They close after a while (hard to tell how long) but some days it reaches our max (server by Atlas, max 4K connections).

I tried to set maxconnections property to 100, tried to set to close automatically any connection after 5000MS - but both are ignored.

I've taken a look at the driver documentation - but seems that connection pooling options are not available in the PHP Mongodb driver. I didn't manage to understand if the options are not available (but the driver manages those autonomously, or if this does not exist at all).

So in general, I find myself in a situation that 1000 users manage to exceed the max 4k connections available - and not sure how to close the connections.

Comment: How is this a coding question ?

Comment: Write a small script that performs simple operations, then hit it with a tool like `siege` to generate load. When you can reproduce the problem add the script to the question.

Comment: Also when you say "driver documentation" add links to all of the documentation you are referencing.

Comment: @maxMuster It is a coding question because before I assume there is a problem with the driver I must assume there is something in my code that does not utilize the driver correctly. The driver utilization is implemented by code and I hoped to get some direction into a common mistake or so. Cheers

Comment: @D.sM Thanks, interesting debugging direction, I'll try that.